# Swift import error with MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1

Tags: ios, swift, ibm-mobilefirst

When i try to`#import  <IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.h>`
into the Bridging header for swift 2.0, the app fails.

I am using WL api in Swift code and trying to add the worklight header to ProjectName-Bridging-Header.h

I am using MobileFirst Platform Foundation 7.1.

I generated the app using mfp push.

I am using Xcode Version 7.1 (7B91b).

When i import IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid in swift code, i get Could not build Objective-C module.

When i try to import it on Bridging header, i get could not build module IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.

Comment: The app fails how? Why don't you provide the error message...? What is the Xcode version? How did you add the framework? Manually, or with CocoaPods?

Comment: Added detailed information to the question.

Comment: Same issue here, using pod install.  "pod install" completes fine, but import statement shows code error about not being able to find requested module. Tried several variants. XCode 7.1 seems to have broken something.  

I'm using the following import statement:
import IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundation

Comment: I created a simple project called Test with mfp create command and added a swift file into the project. Everything worked fine, but once i try to import mobilefirst foundation headers, i am getting the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think i have a solution for this issue:

Go to Project Settings -

Search for Swift

There is a property called Import Paths:

Add: "$(SRCROOT)/Frameworks/IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.framework/Modules "

Make sure your IBMMobileFirstPlatformFoundationHybrid.framework resides in the Framework folder. If not you need to change the path. If you inspect the framework content, there is a file called module.modulemap. I am not sure why this file in not automatically detected by setting the Framework search path. For some reason, the swift part does not detect modulemap inside the framework. This may not be optimal answer, but it works. In discussion with some MFP experts and if i get better answer, i will update.